# dump subset of table

Tags: postgresql

I want to dump a subset of a table of my postgres database. Is there a way to dump a SELECT statement without creating a view?

I need to copy a part of the table to an other postgres database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) to dump it directly to disk.

Example (from the fine manual) using a SELECT:

```
COPY 
(SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_name LIKE 'A%') 
TO '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/a_list_countries.copy';
```

Comment: Note that this copies the data to the server. If you want to dump data to your machine (specifically where `psql` is called from) then you can replace `COPY` with `\copy`. Useful when dumping data from remote database where available storage space may be limited.